# calculus applied to fields in physics

Tags: calculus, geometry, applications, differential

Having trouble with the maths in this question, I realise this is a physics question so I apologise if this isn't allowed, but some mathematicians might be able to solve it well. I asked this in the physics stack exchange and they all freaked out cos its a worked example question and not conceptual of nature so I thought I'd try it here. can anyone help or show me how to solve? please and thank you.
A $120\ $mm long metallic rod with a diameter of $11\ $mm is insulated so that heat can only flow in and out of the
rod at one end (defined as $x = 0$). This end of the rod is maintained at $18\ ^◦$C while the initial temperature in
the rod takes the form of part of a sine wave with a maximum temperature of $65\ ^◦$C.

(a) Show that a temperature profile of the form
$$T(x, t) = T_A \sin{2πx\over λ}e^{−t/τ} + T_0$$
is a solution of the temperature diffusion equation when the diffusion constant, $D$, is a function of one or
more of the constants $T_A$, $T_0$, λ and τ . Determine this relationship. Note that you are not asked to solve
the diffusion equation - just to show that the form given satisfies the equation.

(b) The boundary condition at the ends of the rod must be

Constant temperature end: $\displaystyle {∂T\over ∂t}(0, t) = 0$,

Insulated end: $\displaystyle {∂T\over ∂x}(L, t) = 0$,

where $L$ is the length of the rod. Give brief explanations of why these conditions apply for the current
situation.

(c) Using the boundary and initial conditions provided, find numerical values for $T_A$, $T_0$ and λ.

(d) The rod cools over time as heat is lost through the non-insulated end. Suppose it takes $25\ $s for the peak
temperature of the rod to drop to $32\ ^◦$C. Calculate a numerical value for τ and hence find $D$.

Comment: plz my mathematical overlords, have mercy on a puny cretin like myself and help me solve this easy question

Comment: You are usually expected to provide evidence of your own efforts to solve these problems. What have you tried?

Comment: well I know that the diffusion equation is hx = -k(dt/dx)

Comment: and dT/dt = D(dT^2/dx^2)

Comment: but can't figure out how to make the equation displayed in A in that form

Comment: @johnsmith: I agree with the people from stackexchange that say that the members should not solve the problems but instead guide them in the concepts that allow those that put the question to learn and solve the problem by themselves. I guess you might get better help in the physics section of stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah but I posted in there simply asking how can the free end of the rod be constant if what is flowing out of there, not even asking them to solve and they all freaked out, and then some people told me that they don't take kindly to people asking questions that require computation. no idea why. I then noticed that all the questions were conceptual and philosophical in nature. not "worked example problems"

Comment: Just plug the given $T(x,t)$ into your equations and check they are satisfied, provided $D$ is related to the given constants in a suitable way.

Answer (score 0):

(a) You must check that the given function $T(x,t)$ satisfies the diffusion equation
$$
{\partial T\over\partial t}=D{\partial^2 T\over\partial x^2}.
$$
We have:
$$
{\partial T\over\partial t}=-{1\over\tau}T_A \sin{2\pi x\over\lambda}e^{−t/\tau},
\quad
{\partial^2 T\over\partial x^2}=-\left({2\pi\over\lambda}\right)^2T_A \sin{2\pi x\over\lambda}e^{−t/\tau}.
$$
Hence:
$$
{\partial T\over\partial t}={\lambda^2\over4\pi^2\tau}{\partial^2 T\over\partial x^2},
$$
and this is indeed the diffusion equation, provided:
$$
D={\lambda^2\over4\pi^2\tau}.
$$
I leave to you now to discuss points (b)-(d).